# How to prevent CXF secured webservices access from browser

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, cxf, ws-security

I am developing a basic WebService example using CXF and Spring.
Here are my classes:

```
public interface AuthService {
 @WebMethod
   Person getPerson(@WebParam(name="user_id") Long userId);
}
```

The WS implementation is as follow:

```
public class AuthServiceImpl implements AuthService{

public Person getPerson(Long gid) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setUserId(gid);
    p.setEmail("test"+gid+"@test.de");
    p.setName("test"+gid);

    return p;
}

}
```

My web.xml is as follow:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>    
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My cxf-beans.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml"/>


<bean id="logInBound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
<bean id="logOutBound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
</beans>
```

Here is my cxf-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
  xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
<jaxws:server id="jaxwsService" serviceClass="com.iptech.cxfws.service.AuthService" address="/auth_user">
<jaxws:serviceBean>
    <bean class="com.iptech.cxfws.service.impl.AuthServiceImpl" />
</jaxws:serviceBean>


<jaxws:inInterceptors>
  <ref bean="interceptor"/>
</jaxws:inInterceptors>
</jaxws:server>

<bean id="interceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
 <constructor-arg>
   <map>
     <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
     <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
     <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
            <ref bean="passwordCallback" />
     </entry>
   </map>
 </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="passwordCallback" class="com.iptech.cxfws.service.callback.ServerPasswordCallback"/>

</beans>
```

And finally is my ServerPasswordCallback class:

```
public class ServerPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

    WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
    String username = pc.getIdentifier();
    String password = //get it from a business class
    pc.setPassword(password);
}
```

}

As you can see this is a very simple example you can find in every CXF basic tutorial.
Now, I have two problems:
1) When I call

```
http://localhost:8080/cxf-ws/auth_user/getPerson?user_id=11
```

from Internet browser (Chrome) I get a response, no username/password verification is done. However, when invoking the WS from a Java client, I can't get the response without including username/password in the SOAP message header. Is this normal ?
2) The second question has nothing to do with WS-Security. When deploying/publishing my WS to Tomcat, everything works as expected (except the security issue mentioned above). But, I have the following exception:

```
    javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element 
(URI : "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery", local : "Probe"). 
Expected elements are <{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}AppSequence>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Bye>,
<{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}EndpointReference>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Hello>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}MetadataVersion>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Probe>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}ProbeMatches>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Resolve>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}ResolveMatches>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Scopes>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Security>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Sig>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}SupportedMatchingRules>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Types>,
<{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}XAddrs>
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to CXF 2.7.1 or change to using WS-SecurityPolicy.

Comment: I am actually using CXF 2.7.0 which is currently the latest release as I can read in their download page.

Comment: 2.7.1 was released earlier this week. Available on the download page, forgot to update the main "news" section.

Comment: @DanielKulp To assist other users that encounter this question, was there a specific issue that was fixed in 2.7.1 that you can point us to?

Comment: I found this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4629 hope it helps